# Android app with locale language not display text properly on components

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I was having some problem when trying to set the Android app to read from different strings.xml based on the shared preference set.

When the user chooses from the language selections, I am setting the shared preference:

```
public void setLocale(String localeName) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("LANGUAGE_SHARED_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("selected_language_key", localeName).apply();
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this.getContext(), MainActivity_.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    dismiss();
}
```

In my MainActivity, I get the shared preference by the following code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("LANGUAGE_SHARED_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString("selected_language_key", "en");
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    System.out.println("Test " + getString(R.string.maintenance_and_service));
```

I printed out test line to see if the function above works. I changed from English to Chinese and vice versa, it works well. However, when the shared preference is set to read Chinese, when I move to next fragment from MainActivity, the text printed out in the button in next fragment is still English. My XML for button in next fragment:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMaintenanceService"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_settings_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_settings_height"
        style="@style/Button.settings"
        android:text="@string/button_maintenance_service"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonRunHistory"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonRunHistory"/>
```

How do I actually let the user select a preferred language, then use the XML file of the selected language for the entire app?

My values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="maintenance_and_service">Maintenance and Service</string>
```

My values-zh/strings.xml:

```
<string name="maintenance_and_service">维修</string>
```

Comment: Does your problem occur when the app closed (not suspended but killed) and freshly started?

Comment: Yeap it will always printed out the selected language. But then when I try to use that string onto some components, it keeps show the English one

Comment: post your string xml files

Comment: @Bek Updated question!

Comment: @dummygg Android has a very good language support at the system level, so please consider very carefully if you really need to complicate your life so much with in-app language support as well. You're gonna face real troubles with it. What I recommend you instead, is to drive the user to the system level Settings page where the user can change the phone (system wide) language directly. Your app strings will be picked up automagically.
I assume you've all the strings into both the languages.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is what I did to change locale in app.

I think `config.setLocale(...)` and `Locale.setDefault(...)` should be checked.

```
Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
} else {
    config.locale = locale;
}

res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        if (config.getLocales().size() > 0) {
            Locale.setDefault(config.getLocales().get(0));
        } else {
            Locale.setDefault(config.locale);
        }
    } else {
        Locale.setDefault(config.locale);
}
```

Comment: Nope it does not work. I tried already, the printed text is correct but then not the text in Android components :(

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After changing your locale restart your app using this code.

```
    Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But in your case you open a new Activity. Check if `chinese` version of `button_maintenance_service` exist.

Comment: Hey sorry it is not working still. I managed to print out the chinese text from SOP though. Just that when I preset the "android:text="@string/..." for Android component is not taking the chinese version

Comment: post full default and chinese version of your strings xml. you posted only `maintenance_and_service` not `button_maintenance_service` . your button text  takes `android:text="@string/button_maintenance_service"`. try to replace button text with `android:text="@string/maintenance_and_service"`